# Expected ';' after method prototype & Method definition not found

Tags: objective-c

I'm going through a coding tutorial and I'm getting an error in my code. 
Here is the tutorial https://www.appcoda.com/sqlite-database-ios-app-tutorial/

The code I've written so far is below. I am getting two errors.

Error 1:

> Expected ';' after method prototype

This shows up on line 17: `-(void)copyDatabaseIntoDocumentsDirectory{`

Error 2:

> Method definition for 'copyDatabaseIntoDocumentsDirectory' not found

This shows up on line 35: `@implementation DBManager`

I can't figure out how to fix it. Can anyone help? Thanks.

```
//
//  DBManager.m
//  SQLite3DBSample
//
//  Created by Jean Wong on 4/21/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 Jean Wong. All rights reserved.
//

#import "DBManager.h"
#import <sqlite3.h>

@interface DBManager()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *documentsDirectory;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *databaseFilename;

-(void)copyDatabaseIntoDocumentsDirectory{
    // Check if the database file exists in the documents directory.
    NSString *destinationPath = [self.documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.databaseFilename];
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:destinationPath]) {
        // The database file does not exist in the documents directory, so copy it from the main bundle now.
        NSString *sourcePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.databaseFilename];
        NSError *error;
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:sourcePath toPath:destinationPath error:&error];

        // Check if any error occurred during copying and display it.
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }
}

@end

@implementation DBManager
-(instancetype)initWithDatabaseFilename:(NSString *)dbFilename{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Set the documents directory path to the documentsDirectory property.
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        self.documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        // Keep the database filename.
        self.databaseFilename = dbFilename;

        // Copy the database file into the documents directory if necessary.
        [self copyDatabaseIntoDocumentsDirectory];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Comment: Hi Jean. Welcome to SO. Please have a look here to learn how to improve your questions (eg. formatting): https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

In `@interface` you should just declare the prototypes or properties not implementation, you should implement the methods in `@implementation` part.

```
@interface DBManager()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *documentsDirectory;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *databaseFilename;

@end


@implementation DBManager
-(instancetype)initWithDatabaseFilename:(NSString *)dbFilename{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Set the documents directory path to the documentsDirectory property.
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        self.documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        // Keep the database filename.
        self.databaseFilename = dbFilename;

        // Copy the database file into the documents directory if necessary.
        [self copyDatabaseIntoDocumentsDirectory];
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)copyDatabaseIntoDocumentsDirectory{
    // Check if the database file exists in the documents directory.
    NSString *destinationPath = [self.documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.databaseFilename];
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:destinationPath]) {
        // The database file does not exist in the documents directory, so copy it from the main bundle now.
        NSString *sourcePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.databaseFilename];
        NSError *error;
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:sourcePath toPath:destinationPath error:&error];

    // Check if any error occurred during copying and display it.
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: declare, not define.